Bluetooth headset connecting but no audio. Buggy workaround a2dp
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1. Whenever I am connecting a Bluetooth headset it is being connected but no audio is being heard. I have already played around with pavucontrol, bluez and blueman (including reinstalling them). I have already changed from pulse audio to pipe wire but still the problem persists. When I try to switch from A2DP to handsfree mode, the audio quality significantly drops. The only work around I have found is that I have to disconnect the headset from my computer, then connect it to my smartphone, play some audio in the smartphone then reconnecting the headset to my computer, and only then I am able to hear any audio (in A2DP mode). Sometimes the audio playback stops automatically and then I have to read you this work around once again. Also have to do this work around every time I connect my headset to the computer. Please suggest any fix. Thanks in advance!
NOTE : I have faced this issue only with Realme Buds Wireless 3.
I have an Amazon Echo with which I have not faced this issue.

Does this workaround help? -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1536639/289138

@Hannu no this is not working.

Hmm... I added a couple of alternative lines. Try?

@Hannu I have tried the alternative..still not working unfortunately. Could this be a device specific issue?

Hmm? See if $ bluetoothctl, agent on, scan on gives any clues? help for more menus and commands.
